# Incrementally process large XML file over HTTPS?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, http, azure

I've got to download, process, and store an 8GB XML file from a secure web server. I could download the file using the `WebRequest` class, but this will take a VERY long time. Also, I know that the file is structured in such a way that it suits processing in discrete chunks.

How can I 'stream' this file such that I only get bite-size pieces which I can work on, without having to get the whole stream at one time?

**Edit**

I forgot to mention - we are hosted on Azure. An idea that comes to mind is to provision a worker role which just downloads large files and can take as long as it wants.  How feasible would that be?

Comment: HTTP does support "range" requests... although that's manual, and requires knowledge of the DOM/ranges. Is it at all possible to run a service on the web-server?

Comment: hi @pst thanks for the suggestion, we don't own that particular web server, so I think the answer is "no"... I'll look into range requests anyway fmi so thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

8 GB is a large workload. To protect myself from rework and to scale effectively, I would decouple the XML file download from it’s processing.

While downloading as a stream, I would write some sort of stream identifier to persistent storage and schedule each atomic unit of work to be done by placing a message with its relevant data on a queue.
This would allow recovery from the download going south for any reason or a unit of work being unsuccessful and/or interfering with the download.

Comment: thanks @Lucifure I'm definitely thinking along these lines, and Azure allows for this sort of approach.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using HttpWebRequest, BeginGetResponse then GetResponseStream

Then one can read the stream in chunks as it's dripping down via stream.BeginRead

Here's much too complicated example:
http://stuff.seans.com/2009/01/05/using-httpwebrequest-for-asynchronous-downloads/

Comment: But that's still *sequential* access :(

Comment: indeed, sequential access will do nicely. I'll check out the example thanks.

Comment: @Agent_L Very true, so +1. However, have fun with 8GB's and hoping it doesn't hiccup in the middle ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to process file sequentially just open an XMLReader on the stream of response and read the data as needed.

If you need random access to the file (i.e. read in the middle) you may need to do more work to create seekable stream (if server supports RANGE option in the request) or simply download whole file as you do now.

Please note that 8GB is large amount of data and downloading it completely will take a lot of time irrespective of method of reading.

Comment: Won't the XML be invalid until you hit the closing tag?

Comment: If you care for verifying if file is valid XML first - yes, you have to read it to the end. In most cases you don't need that as you trust source enough. You can also validate at the end: read sequentially, process as you go, throw away results if turns out to be invalid XML.

Comment: I was thinking that the XmlReader would throw a parsing error, so you would have to construct valid XML before using the reader. I'm also wondering how to track which items have been processed.

Comment: XmlReader does not read anything before you ask it it to and even than it reads only what you ask (i.e. single element), you are probably thinking about XmlDocument.Load which indeed verifies whole document.

Answer (score 1):

You could upload the xml file to a block blob and download it from there.This blog post might help http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2011/05/30/asynchronous-parallel-block-blob-transfers-with-progress-change-notification.aspx

Hope this helps.